# How can I increase the maximum speaker volume?

Tags: audio, volume-control

**Is there a way, maybe even with root, to increase the maximum speaker volume?**

I own a Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet, which are known for their crappy and quiet speaker. There are ways to replace the speaker with another one. But I'd like to know a generic, not device related, software based method to increase the maximum volume on Android (if there is one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an app which can do it for you...
Try the free one first, and if it works, then buy the full version :)

Free: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.FREE.android.lvh&feature=search_result

Payed: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.TEST.android.lvh&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5URVNULmFuZHJvaWQubHZoIl0.

Have a great day :)

Comment: Was it the right solution for you? Like to know, and if isn't the right answer i like to search some more for you :)

Comment: Well, Volume+ seems to need either a Cyanogen Mod or a MIUI ROM. That is both not available on my TPT. But I am aware that this may be only achieved on custom ROMs/Kernels and/or with root. I hadn't the time yet to test it.

Comment: It works well on my stock Galaxy Nexus... Sure you have read it correct?

Comment: But i think you need root, but i'm not sure, since i always have root :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the 'DSP manager' application from cyanogen community.

Download application here[dsp manager for stock ROM's](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?s=5744f1e77cda6b5e64763719213e58fb&p=20404229&postcount=1)