# How to increase speaker volume on tablet

Tags: audio, 4.3-jelly-bean, sony-xperia-z

The speaker and headphone volumes on my xperia z tablet are too low. Is there any way to increase the max volume that works in 4.3 ?

Comment: See: [How can I boost the volume on my Droid's speaker?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1262/16575) / [How can I boost the music volume higher than the max limit?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30527/16575) / [How can I make my Samsung Galaxy Nexus volume go louder than what stock allows?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17319/16575) / [How can I increase the maximum speaker volume?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/19426/16575)

Comment: @Izzy Most (all?) of those require you to be root or to be running an older OS don't they?  For example Volume+ FREE says "This Application is ONLY for phones running Gingerbread."

Comment: I cannot tell. As I'm not affected of the problem myself, I felt no need to test the solutions on all possible device/version combinations :) Neither did I say your question is duplicate/obsolete. Above comment was rather intended as a hint to possible solutions (sorry if I wasn't clear enough about that, I should have explicitly mentioned it). You might wish to [edit] your question and write what you already tried, or why this-and-that doesn't work for you. That would help to narrow down things. Thanks!